# Xcode duplicate symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Any suggestions please:

```
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:
        /Users/retributionxd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RevEye-doarrfgrbaqxejbxnrhmfdcgqgka/Build/Intermediates/RevEye.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RevEye.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability.o
        /Users/retributionxd/Desktop/amar/reveye/RevEye/WikitudeSDK.framework/WikitudeSDK(Reachability.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in:
        /Users/retributionxd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RevEye-doarrfgrbaqxejbxnrhmfdcgqgka/Build/Intermediates/RevEye.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RevEye.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability.o
        /Users/retributionxd/Desktop/amar/reveye/RevEye/WikitudeSDK.framework/WikitudeSDK(Reachability.o)
    ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Error statement:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Search for reachability class and see if you have added that class twice. Or it might be showing red.

Comment: It's always possibility that you imported .m file instead of .h file. Just throwing it up here :) it happend to me to many times.

Comment: @BigSzu : I imported .h files only. I checked also.

Comment: @BhavukJain : I checked that class.
1) Not added twice
2) Not showing red

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** Possible solutions

1. Delete your `DerivedData` folder and build again (you should do that from time to time anyway) - start XCode again, clean, build
2. remove `WikitudeSDK.framework` try to build. I can image that you embedded that framework twice, make sure this is not the case by removing one. 
   If it doesnt work, add it again and try to build

Comment: I followed this procedure:
1. Quit Xcode
2. Delete => DerivedData folder
3. OpenXcode 
4. Clean + Build project.


But it is showing same error

Comment: ok, updated my answer. Did you try removing the framework and building?

Comment: what happens if you try to build after removing the framework? Does ist stull build?

Comment: What did you change since then?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WTArchitectView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WikiTudeViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SnapViewControlleriPhone.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Uhm, does this only happen when you build for the simulator or also for a device?

Comment: Any suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error occur due to duplicate of files. Sometimes we use multiple frameworks but those framework have files which other framework have too. So, we need to identify the duplicate file and remove them.