# xCode Cocoapods faily to build project ios(9.3)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I Try to install cocoapods framework one my project .I make pod install and when try to build i get back :

```
Ld /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestSplitView.app/TestSplitView normal x86_64
cd /Users/chris/Desktop/xCodeTrainningProjects/TestSplitView
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Intermediates/TestSplitView.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestSplitView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestSplitView.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework SwiftyJSON -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Intermediates/TestSplitView.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestSplitView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestSplitView.swiftmodule -framework Pods_TestSplitView -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Intermediates/TestSplitView.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestSplitView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestSplitView_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSplitView-fcrizpyzqhsxswdwurudpiyebywu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestSplitView.app/TestSplitView

ld: framework not found SwiftyJSON
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linker command failed with exit code 1 error in Xcode project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811001/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-error-in-xcode-project)

Comment: show the pod file and how you're trying to import SwiftyJSON

Comment: You can also try `pod deintegrate` + `pod install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue crops up for me sometimes.

Make sure you are in your workspace and not your project. Do a project clean first. Build your project without the library import statement (but still with SwiftyJSON pod installed), and then build again with the import statement.